# Print address of iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

Why is it not possible to change the cout line with following in order to get the address of the iterator?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    vector<int> inputs = {15, 20, 10, 5, 19};
    vector<int>::iterator i;
    i = inputs.begin();
    cout << *i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Above example of iterator. Clear.

```
cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: The address of the iterator is &i. If you mean the address of the element, then &(\*i). *Why is it not possible to change the cout* It's possible. Overload the stream output operator.

Comment: OK, great! Thanks for your help! But was it not so that there is e.g. the adress marked with "&" and dereferencing used with "*", e.g. when using pointers in C (or C++). What is "i" then physically if it shows an error message when printing it out?

Comment: Anyway, your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: What is "i" is unspecified. Usually it's some object.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `vector<int>::iterator i; i = inputs.begin();` to `vector<int>::iterator i = inputs.begin();`.

Comment: @GigiHofleitner an iterator may or may not be a pointer, depending on its implementation. But a pointer is a valid iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible because there is no overload for `operator<<` that takes `vector<>::iterator` as its second argument. If you want to print the address of the iterator object, you'd need `&i`.

Or you could overload it yourself:

```cpp
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<int>::iterator &i) {
  os << &i;
  return os;
}
```

[Live sample](https://godbolt.org/z/xvnhaT3Gc)

Answer (score 1):

Lets have a little `C++` lesson.

`&i` is address of a variable
`*i` is deference of pointer
`i` is variable itself

So if you have, `i` is variable:

```
int i = 5;
cout << "print variable i: " << i << "\n";
cout << "print address of variable i: " << &i << "\n";
```

If you have:

```
int* i = new int();
*i = 5;
cout << i << "\n";
```

would give you address where `5` is stored.

```
cout << &i << "\n";
```

would give you an address where pointer to `5` is stored.

```
cout << *i << "\n";
```

would print `5`.

For printing `int` element you can override io operators:

```
// here `&i` is reference to iterator 
//      (address that you cannot change)
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, 
                         const std::vector<int>::iterator &i)
{
    os << *i;
    return os;
}
```

If you go to `cppreference` says that `iterator.bet`
Now in `C++` you have derived types and `iterator` and `vector` are some of them.

There are questions:
What does it mean to print `iterator`? Here is wiki definition

> In computer programming, an iterator is an object that enables a programmer to traverse a container, particularly lists. Various types of iterators are often provided via a container's interface.

In essence it does not make sense to print `iterator` itself (in your case `i`), thus io stream for iterators is not implemented.

Another reason for not implementing IO stream, like it is case for `vector` (`iterators` as well), is that they are template classes, meaning that you can have custom type.

Take this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class myNumb {
public:
    myNumb (int i) : num (i) {}

private:
    int num;
};

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    vector<myNumb> inputs = {15, 20, 10, 5, 19};
    vector<myNumb>::iterator i;
    i = inputs.begin();
    cout << inputs[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you have:

```
class myCoord {
public:
   myCoord (double lo, double la) :
                longitude (lo), latitude(la) {}
private:
   double longitude, latitude;
}
```

So what if we have this:

```
class city {
public:
    city (string n, long p) :
         name (n), population (p)
private:
    string name;
    long population;
    myCoord location;
}
```

So in essence it makes more sense to override is stream for these derived types so you can use them when printing element of `array`, `vector` or `list` or `map` or custom some other container.